# How to combine two plots in one frame by r?

Tags: r, plot

I can create plots of two groups in one window but I don't know how to combine two plots in one frame with same x and y axis lines. The example is as same as the linked image. I would be grateful if someone can help me to do this with R.

[Please click here to view the image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/X7iHRXha60bKqAieeIfj6tckXQqccBoXU7iG3TJrd8GTP00FQC6hY_gBIIvj3jyC7tl4tI0dk5e_aLP5CLhmI56cKm0jvlFBKyUC5vZr_ukgYXSVfig4CQNPIYh8fjTpe5jR30s4GMTE8_q2cN-ZESDC7VAfq6ECCqYXp3vmAAfPOIQYRC5POJUrNC8ro-HKbY16Y3OAJv2BsHK6xUopni5yqUKGcwfIVWSaMnjBe8y-bvpV-vFm-KIZUHwbmVEN0EWldZ-jhENhYbXktNpHtSXnPFRHFn6kkX7YjrKdx4TWQaFlWNp-Q6oVGwu6oSun5A3WF-DxomZaw4zvCdJLECSy4U-TizC2tjtJa1LOVa-gPlfNCi-9mJqQgj3hLLn3Uk2QQeHe6cav6-UrlGHXOGOGxqG308zr3jCE7OVs_NbIGLtOe_Zt2ImRdmcmKvfeMakM1VCjSvVHXK-OTEMFTDz7EblkOYeo3wjd1PL5DP63fNff54YHQKe65xHyxA4EY6uaf1uRvXrRjkuUfuKjIVQBhMBUNF9jle0tN_HkGLU=w788-h510-no)

Comment: More detail needed. What does your data look like and how do you plot it? The boxplot function automatically plots boxes side by side.

Comment: Please provide what we need to help you through a minimal working example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Try, using `cbind` function

```
boxplot(cbind(boxplot1, boxplot2))
```

This will display the two `boxplots` in same frame with combined x and y axes.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
plot(x,y)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x,y)
```